# View vs TableValued Function vs SubQuery

Tags: sql-server, join, view, subquery, table-valued-parameters

I have a scenario where i need to

1. join with **3 tables** to get the value for **one field**
2. for **second field** join with **4 tables**
3. for **third field join** with **3 tables**

***all above joins are inner*** 
and if data exist the value of my field would be "Y" else "N"

```
to achieve this which method gives best performance
```

> 1. create a tablevalued function with which i can join and check if null then "N" else "Y"
> 2. create a view instead table valued function and do join with that
> 3. write subquery and use join with subquery.

which will be faster... this is goin to executed on large data. hence performance is the major factor.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Functions are evil.

Difference between a view and a subquery, on the other hand, will be hardly noticeable - as long as queries are exactly the same, of course. Views will probably be less flexible, though.

Comment: *‘Functions are evil’* is too much of a generalisation. In-line TVFs are quite optimiser-friendly and perfectly fine to use.

Comment: @AndriyM, inline is the only exception. But with regards to performance, as was the topic of this question, I doubt they will beat either views or subqueries. They have their uses, but performance-wise, they are the worst choice.